# How to modify the value in the database

Tags: vb6

Using SQL Server and VB6

Table1

Date Time

```
20090801 060000
20090802 162000
```

Date Format: yyyymmdd
Time Format: HHMMSS

Date & Time Column Datatype is varchar

When i select a Date in a Datetimepicker and modify the time.  The should update in the table.

Expected Output

```
01-08-2009 (DatetimePicker value)
080000 (Textbox value)
```

The Above value should update in the table

How to make a code for the above condition.

Need code help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Dim strDateTime as string

strDateTime = Format$(DateTimePicker.Value, "MMDDYYYY mmhhss")
```

Update our the database with a recordset

```
rs.Fields["DateTimeField"] = strDateTime
rs.Update'
```

I hope this points you in the right direction